Expo crash without any log when submitting images to firebase with Expo Image Picker
I am trying to submit images to firebase Expo crash without any log with Expo Image Picker. But not everytime. Sometimes it works perfect, but sometimes it quits without any error log. I am new and will be happy if anyone helps. I tried several things but result is not change. Here is my code:
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { getFirestore, getDocs, collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getDownloadURL, getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage"
import { app } from '../../firebaseConfig';


export default function AddPostScreen() {

  const storage = getStorage();
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const db = getFirestore(app);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);


const pickImages = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsMultipleSelection: true,
      allowsEditing: false,
      quality: 0,
      base64: true,
      
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      const uris = result?.assets.map((image) => image.uri) ?? [];
      setSelectedImages(uris);
    }
  };

const onSubmitMethod = async (values: any) => {
    setLoading(true);
    values.image = selectedImages;
    values.postId = Date.now().toString();

    const imagePromises = selectedImages.map(async (uri, index) => {
      const response = await fetch(uri);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const imageName = `userPost/${Date.now()}_${index}`; // Unique image name
      const storageRef = ref(storage, imageName);

      setUploading(true); // Start uploading
      await uploadBytes(storageRef, blob);
      setUploading(false); // Finish uploading

      const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
      return downloadURL;
    });

    const imageUrls = await Promise.all(imagePromises);
    values.images = imageUrls;
    values.userName = user.fullName;
    values.userEmail = user.primaryEmailAddress.emailAddress;
    values.userImage = user.imageUrl;
    console.log('Images uploaded:', imageUrls);

    // Add the document with the image URLs to the collection
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'UserPost'), values);
    if (docRef.id) {
      setLoading(false);
      Alert.alert('Təbriklər!', 'Elan uğurla əlavə edildi!')

      // Clear the selected images after upload
      setSelectedImages([]);
    }
  };


return (


